# Angularjs: a factory to share data between controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an angular.js app with multiple views, and I need to preserve status among view change.
So I use a very simple factory to share data.
And, in the controllers, I use the factory name to use my data, instead of "$scope":

```
app.factory('share', function() {
  return {};
}

app.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope, share) {
  share.obj1['a'] = 'ABC';
});

app.controller('SecondCtrl', function ($scope, share) {
  share.obj1['b'] = 'DEF';
  if (share.obj1['a'] === 'ABC') {
    ...
  }
});
```

And, my simplified html view is like this:

```
...
<div ng-repeat="(key, item) in obj1">
  {{item}}
</div>
...
```

This of course doesn't work, because ng-* directives in views only have access to $scope...

Is it possible to keep my data in sync with share factory using $scope?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just do `$scope.share = share` at the end of each controller and of course modify the view:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, item) in share.obj1">
```

Alternatively, and if the structure of `share` is **NOT** going to change (there is always an `obj1`), you could do `angular.extend($scope, share)`. This is **dangerous** if `share` gets new properties, these will not be seen by the scope, until a new controller is created.

Comment: Thanks! I feel quite dumb, on certain moments... :-). However, I did put `$scope.share = share` at the beginning of the controllers... I suppose it doesn't make great difference...